# Update related record without external key

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 2 objects. ObjA and Task. There is no external key (custom field) on Task/ Activity and I am also not allowed to create any custom fields on Activity/ Task

Records from ObjA come from external system and when this record meets certain conditions, task has to be created. Till this point it was easy.

Now, there is a requirement to update ObjA record with associated taskId if task insertion is successful. I am seeing this as challenge because I dont have external key on task.

Here is what I tried. I am sure I am no way close but would like to get some inputs from the community.

```
List<ObjA__c> ObjARecords = trigger.new;
Map<Id, Task> idMap = new Map<Id, Task>();
for(ObjA__c record : ObjARecords) {
   if(record.status == 'Not Started') Continue;
   Task T = new Task(subject = 'New Item', status = 'Not Started', Priority = 'High');
   idMap.put(record.Id, t);
}

        Database.SaveResult[] SR = Database.insert(idMap.values(), False);
        for(Integer i = 0; i < SR.size(); i++){
            if(!SR[i].isSuccess()){
//these are the failed tasks. Not sure how to proceed next.
            }
        }
```

Comment: May be i am missing something, when you create/ insert a task the objA can be referenced as the related to object which then automatically builds a 2 way access from task to object and object to multiple tasks. why do you need a trigger to start with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you will use this code in a "Before Insert" trigger. Otherwise, you'd need to requery the inserted objects to be able to do DML. Because of it, you cannot use the ID of objA, since it doesn't yet exist.

Here goes an example:

```
List<ObjA__c> ObjARecords = trigger.new;
Map<Integer, Integer> idMap = new Map<Integer, Integer>();

Integer objaOrder = -1;
Integer taskOrder = -1;
List<Task> tasksToInsert = new List<Task>();

for(ObjA__c record : ObjARecords) {
   objaOrder += 1;

   if(record.status == 'Not Started') Continue;

   taskOrder += 1;  
   Task T = new Task(subject = 'New Item', status = 'Not Started', Priority = 'High');
   tasksToInsert.add(T);

   idMap.put(taskOrder, objaOrder);
}

Database.SaveResult[] SR = Database.insert(tasksToInsert, false);
for(Integer i = 0; i < SR.size(); i++){
  if(!SR[i].isSuccess()){
    //these are the failed tasks. Not sure how to proceed next.
    //Up to you if you want to do something here
  } else {
    objARecord = idMap.get(i);

    ObjARecords[objARecord].TaskId = SR[i].getId();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for your input. Working on this and will let u know :)

Comment: I have a question. If we are writing this in before insert of ObjA context, what if the insertion of ObjA fails ? It looks like task will still be created.

Comment: Depends on the context. I am not 100% sure (drawing a blank) but IIRC, the entire context would get rolled back, including the tasks. I would test, however, before believing this 100%

Comment: Unhandled exception would roll back the whole transaction. But when you set `allOrNone` to false, there is no exception to catch.

Comment: ^^ @pmvsdt that is your answer. You can fairly easily shift this to your afterinsert trigger. The main difference is that you're going to have to gather your ObjA Ids and requery before you can update